# How can I view the code of example Chakra UI components in Storybook

Tags: storybook, chakra-ui

If you use Chakra UI alongside Storybook, it automatically populates examples of all the different Chakra components, shown in the image. But is there a way to view the code that produces these examples, as it would be helpful when making them? I tried looking in the packages but couldn't find where they are located.

[image: Chakra UI in Storybook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the code in their GitHub repo. For example, the `Layout` component is in https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/tree/main/packages/layout

Comment: Perfect, thanks!